# NSString to dictionary? or to json then to dictionary? Getting objects of key for a string

Tags: ios, arrays, json, parsing, dictionary

I have a STRING, then I need it as json so I can parse it and get the objects for keys.

For example, I need all objects of key for ID in an array to display in a table. 
How would I do it with the string?

Suggestions?

Here's the string:

```
{
  "COMMON": {
    "RESULT_CD": "0000",
    "RESULT_MSG": "SUCCESS",
    "CATEGORY": "computing",
    "SVC_ID": "7",
    "TARGET": "list(VM)",
    "REQUEST_DATE": "201410271741",
    "PAGE_NO": 0,
    "NUM_PER_PAGE": 0
  },
  "DATA": {
    "VM_LIST": [
      {
        "@SVC_ID": "7",
        "ID": "VMSPE0000000083",
        "VM_ALIAS": "CV00900000083",
        "VM_OPER_DESC": "Power On",
        "MACHIN_STATUS_DESC": "[150748]success:virtual machine power on",
        "USVC_DESC": "7/Running, No Change r/hurhurhur, Inc.",
        "PURPOSE_NM": "Service_Default",
        "VIRT_TYPE_DESC": "Para Virtualization",
        "SERVER_STATUS_MSG": "VM running",
        "VCPU_CNT": "2",
        "MEM_SIZE_MB": "1024",
        "VNIC_CNT": "1",
        "OS_NAME": "CentOS_6.4_en_64"
      },
      {
        "@SVC_ID": "7",
        "ID": "VMSPE0000000093",
        "VM_ALIAS": "CV00900000093",
        "VM_OPER_DESC": "Reboot",
        "MACHIN_STATUS_DESC": "[150749]success:virtual machine reboot",
        "USVC_DESC": "7/Running, No Change r/hurhurhur, Inc.",
        "PURPOSE_NM": "Service_Default",
        "VIRT_TYPE_DESC": "Para Virtualization",
        "SERVER_STATUS_MSG": "VM running",
        "VCPU_CNT": "1",
        "MEM_SIZE_MB": "2048",
        "VNIC_CNT": "1",
        "OS_NAME": "Gentoo _2011-0 _en_64"
      },
      {
        "@SVC_ID": "7",
        "ID": "VMSPE0000000096",
        "VM_ALIAS": "CV00900000096",
        "VM_OPER_DESC": "Vm Initialization",
        "MACHIN_STATUS_DESC": "[163023]success:virtual machine running",
        "USVC_DESC": "7/Running, No Change r/hurhurhur, Inc.",
        "PURPOSE_NM": "Service_Default",
        "VIRT_TYPE_DESC": "Para Virtualization",
        "SERVER_STATUS_MSG": "VM running",
        "VCPU_CNT": "2",
        "MEM_SIZE_MB": "1024",
        "VNIC_CNT": "1",
        "OS_NAME": "OpenSuse_12.1_en_64"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

EDIT:

Below is what I was able to google.

```
NSDictionary *JSON =
                 [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: [response dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                                 options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                   error:nil];
```

BUT, compare the string NSLog to the JSON NSLog!!

String:

```
{
  "COMMON": {
    "RESULT_CD": "0000",
    "RESULT_MSG": "SUCCESS",
    "CATEGORY": "computing",
    "SVC_ID": "7",
    "TARGET": "list(VM)",
    "REQUEST_DATE": "201410271757",
    "PAGE_NO": 0,
    "NUM_PER_PAGE": 0
  },
  "DATA": {
    "VM_LIST": [
      {
        "@SVC_ID": "7",
        "ID": "VMSPE0000000083",
        "VM_ALIAS": "CV00900000083",
        "VM_OPER_DESC": "Power On",
        "MACHIN_STATUS_DESC": "[150748]success:virtual machine power on",
        "USVC_DESC": "7/Running, No Change r/hurhurhur, Inc.",
        "PURPOSE_NM": "Service_Default",
        "VIRT_TYPE_DESC": "Para Virtualization",
        "SERVER_STATUS_MSG": "VM running",
        "VCPU_CNT": "2",
        "MEM_SIZE_MB": "1024",
        "VNIC_CNT": "1",
        "OS_NAME": "CentOS_6.4_en_64"
      },
      {
        "@SVC_ID": "7",
        "ID": "VMSPE0000000093",
        "VM_ALIAS": "CV00900000093",
        "VM_OPER_DESC": "Reboot",
        "MACHIN_STATUS_DESC": "[150749]success:virtual machine reboot",
        "USVC_DESC": "7/Running, No Change r/hurhurhur, Inc.",
        "PURPOSE_NM": "Service_Default",
        "VIRT_TYPE_DESC": "Para Virtualization",
        "SERVER_STATUS_MSG": "VM running",
        "VCPU_CNT": "1",
        "MEM_SIZE_MB": "2048",
        "VNIC_CNT": "1",
        "OS_NAME": "Gentoo _2011-0 _en_64"
      },
      {
        "@SVC_ID": "7",
        "ID": "VMSPE0000000096",
        "VM_ALIAS": "CV00900000096",
        "VM_OPER_DESC": "Vm Initialization",
        "MACHIN_STATUS_DESC": "[163023]success:virtual machine running",
        "USVC_DESC": "7/Running, No Change r/hurhurhur, Inc.",
        "PURPOSE_NM": "Service_Default",
        "VIRT_TYPE_DESC": "Para Virtualization",
        "SERVER_STATUS_MSG": "VM running",
        "VCPU_CNT": "2",
        "MEM_SIZE_MB": "1024",
        "VNIC_CNT": "1",
        "OS_NAME": "OpenSuse_12.1_en_64"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

JSON:

```
{
    COMMON =     {
        CATEGORY = computing;
        "NUM_PER_PAGE" = 0;
        "PAGE_NO" = 0;
        "REQUEST_DATE" = 201410271757;
        "RESULT_CD" = 0000;
        "RESULT_MSG" = SUCCESS;
        "SVC_ID" = 7;
        TARGET = "list(VM)";
    };
    DATA =     {
        "VM_LIST" =         (
                        {
                "@SVC_ID" = 7;
                ID = VMSPE0000000083;
                "MACHIN_STATUS_DESC" = "[150748]success:virtual machine power on";
                "MEM_SIZE_MB" = 1024;
                "OS_NAME" = "CentOS_6.4_en_64";
                "PURPOSE_NM" = "Service_Default";
                "SERVER_STATUS_MSG" = "VM running";
                "USVC_DESC" = "7/Running, No Change r/hurhurhur, Inc.";
                "VCPU_CNT" = 2;
                "VIRT_TYPE_DESC" = "Para Virtualization";
                "VM_ALIAS" = CV00900000083;
                "VM_OPER_DESC" = "Power On";
                "VNIC_CNT" = 1;
            },
                        {
                "@SVC_ID" = 7;
                ID = VMSPE0000000093;
                "MACHIN_STATUS_DESC" = "[150749]success:virtual machine reboot";
                "MEM_SIZE_MB" = 2048;
                "OS_NAME" = "Gentoo _2011-0 _en_64";
                "PURPOSE_NM" = "Service_Default";
                "SERVER_STATUS_MSG" = "VM running";
                "USVC_DESC" = "7/Running, No Change r/hurhurhur, Inc.";
                "VCPU_CNT" = 1;
                "VIRT_TYPE_DESC" = "Para Virtualization";
                "VM_ALIAS" = CV00900000093;
                "VM_OPER_DESC" = Reboot;
                "VNIC_CNT" = 1;
            },
                        {
                "@SVC_ID" = 7;
                ID = VMSPE0000000096;
                "MACHIN_STATUS_DESC" = "[163023]success:virtual machine running";
                "MEM_SIZE_MB" = 1024;
                "OS_NAME" = "OpenSuse_12.1_en_64";
                "PURPOSE_NM" = "Service_Default";
                "SERVER_STATUS_MSG" = "VM running";
                "USVC_DESC" = "7/Running, No Change r/hurhurhur, Inc.";
                "VCPU_CNT" = 2;
                "VIRT_TYPE_DESC" = "Para Virtualization";
                "VM_ALIAS" = CV00900000096;
                "VM_OPER_DESC" = "Vm Initialization";
                "VNIC_CNT" = 1;
            }
        );
    };
}
```

The json is missing things!!

Is that alright???

Comment: Do you know anything about `NSJSONSerialization` ?

Comment: ...or about Google, for that matter?

Comment: Your JSON was successfully parsed to `NSDictionary`. What you see in console is just `-description` (string representation) of that `NSDictionary` and it does not look as JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first store above string in array then you can use following to convert it into jsonobject

```
[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[yourArray dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:0 error:NULL]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert NSString to Json Format using inbuilt iOS  functionality called `NSJSONSerialization`. for that you have to convert NSString to NSData.

```
// jsonString = your string
NSError *err;
NSData *data = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
id objectChecker = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&err];

if ([objectChecker isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
{
    //your object is NSArray.
}
else if([objectChecker isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
{
    //your object is NSDictionary.
}
else 
{
    //your string doesn't contain proper json format.
}
```

Maybe this will help you. :)